# Inversion of Rose Curve in Unit Circle

Tags: polar-coordinates

The inversion of a polar curve $r(t)$ in the unit circle is given by $1/r(t)$.

A rose is a polar curve defined (up to similarity) by an equation of the form:

$r(t) = \cos(nt)$ or $r(t) = \cos(\frac{p}{q}\cdot t)$

Does the inversion of a rose curve have a name?

eg. $r(t)=1/\cos(2 t)$.

Comment: I don't know a name, but if I were to give it one, I would say it's a "sunshine curve" https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oi9eifga0m

Comment: Yes the [Epispiral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Epispiral.html)